# how to write and parse an a2l file

Tags: a2lix-translation

I need some help from the community. I'm trying to write a macro in vba that allows me to generate an a2l file. I found some guides on the net but it is not enough. It's my very first approaching and I find them unclear.
I ask you if anyone can help me find a detailed guide on what are the characteristics of an a2l file and how to interpret it.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean that A2L = ASAM 2MC? If yes,

Please check ([PyA2L](https://github.com/christoph2/pyA2L)) - looks like some people use it even I haven't tried yet. Maybe you can do something with it.

Personally I made my own A2L parser (my own project [AutoExtractGui](https://sourceforge.net/projects/autoextract/)) but I realized that it takes quite big efforts, still having some bugs/issues/... not easy. I am using C# and even C# is one of most high-level language it needs very long code for A2L parsing especially.

Even you try to make your own parser, still you need to understand the A2L's format, meaning, how to use the contents, ... this is additional task you need to study/understand/look inside deeply. Good to study, it is true, but it also needs your big efforts. ASAM standard is still being updated and tools (INCA/CANape/...) are also being updated, A2L contents are also updated time by time. If you make your own parser then you should be ready to consume efforts for those topics.

Maybe such already-existing tools/projects might help your job I guess.

Comment: How much does it take to parse a2l of ~80mb (4Million lines) with the library that you develop? I tried PyA2L and it takes around 15 minutes. In the company that I worked they made one parser with .NET C# and as far as I experienced it parses almost immediately.